# Creating a base response for API calls

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create an API by using django-rest-framework. So far I've managed to setup one endpoint of API and managed to fetch all items. A basic response (without the BaseResponse class described later) would look like this:

```
[
    {
        "uuid": "1db6a08d-ec63-4beb-8b41-9b042c53ab83",
        "created_at": "2018-03-12T19:25:07.073620Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-03-12T19:25:37.904350Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "random_name": "random name"
    }
]
```

The result I would like to achieve would be something like this:

```
[
    "success": true
    "message": "Some exception message",
    "data" :{
        "uuid": "1db6a08d-ec63-4beb-8b41-9b042c53ab83",
        "created_at": "2018-03-12T19:25:07.073620Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-03-12T19:25:37.904350Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "random_name": "random name"
    }
]
```

I managed to achieve this by creating a `BaseReponse` class and in view I simply return BaseResponse.to_dict() (a method that I have created inside of class).

```
class BaseResponse(object):

    data = None
    success = False
    message = None

    def __init__(self, data, exception):
        self.data = data
        self.message = str(exception) if exception is not None else None
        self.success = exception is None

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'success': self.success,
            'message': self.message,
            'data': self.data,
        }
```

View:

```
class RandomModelList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        exception = None
        models = None
        try:
            models = RandomModel.objects.all()
        except Exception as e:
            exception = e
        serializer = RandomModelSerializer(models, many=True)

        base_response = BaseResponse(data=serializer.data, exception=exception)

        return Response(base_response.to_dict())
```

I want to mention that with the current code everything its working as expected but I have a huge double about the code (I just feel like I reinvented the wheel). Can someone tell me if this is the optimal solution for my problem and if not what should I change/use?

Comment: well..... looks fine for me.... another option would be using the viewset of DRF, specifically the ListModelMixin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Custom Renderer instead. Something like

```
class CustomRenderer(JSONRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        resp = {
        'data': data
        }
        return super(CustomRenderer, self).render(resp, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

Then create a middleware like

```
class CustomResponseMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response.data.update({'success': is_client_error(response.status_code) or is_server_error(response.status_code)})
    return response
```